# Can we call Tapped and Command at the same time from Label.GestureRecognizers?

Tags: maui

I have list of labels in the ObservableCollection

```
public ObservableCollection<string> DisplayTaskCollection { get; set; }
```

and are displayed in the xaml file like below

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" IsVisible="{Binding AddedTaskVisible}">
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayTaskCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceEventName=PropertyChanged}" >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}"  >
                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding EditTaskCommand}" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
```

Now I need an option to click on only Top most label and goto Command method in the ViewModel. If I know which label is clicked I will take that as a Input.

This is my ViewModel code

```
public RelayCommand EditTaskCommand { get; set; }

EditTaskCommand = new RelayCommand(EditTask);

 private void EditTask()
    {
        //Here If i have a clicked label i will take that as a input then do rest of needed work here
    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking.  Do you want to know if you can use both the event handler and the command?  Or are you asking how to know which label was tapped using the command?  You can do that by using the `CommandParameter` binding

Comment: @Jason I wanted to Click on the Label and also pass the clicked Label value to ViewModel. Used Command Parameter and it worked.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question first:
Technically, yes. Nothing is stopping you.

However...
I do not think that this is what you want.

Using CommunityToolkit.MVVM, you can do the following:

In page xaml:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer 
   Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MyViewModel}}, Path=TappedCommand}"
   CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
```

At the top of the page:

```
xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyViewModelNamespace"
```

And in the ViewModel you have:

```
[RelayCommand]
async Task Tapped(string param){
   ...
}
```

To clarify a bit, because it can be complicated at first:

Once you bind your CollectionView source, it will search up for parent (ancestor type) that contains this source, and bind the command to the tap gesture. And then you can bind the parameter the usual way.

Comment: Thanks a lot This worked like a champ. I accepted the answer